# ios app layout on device is not the same as on the Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6. I am developing a universal app. I made the main screen layout adjust when device is in portrait or landscape by settings constraints.

The problem is that the buttons adjust properly on the iOS simulator, but when i test it on the iPhone 5s the landscape screen does not change its layout and buttons appear outside the screen 
i.e. layout is the same as in portrait mode.

I was playing around with the constraints for a few days now and just can't figure out why its not working.

Comment: can you upload the code if it is not a problem?

Comment: i forgot to mention i am using storyboards

Comment: This is how it looks on the simulator:
[picture1](https://imageshack.com/i/eyIg8im0p)
[picture2](https://imageshack.com/i/ewi0DF4ep)

And on the actual device:
[picture1](https://imageshack.com/i/ezoI4uWAp)
[picture2](https://imageshack.com/i/ezWV5Y8Dp)

Comment: Make sure that the constraint is not marked to be removed at build time. Select the constraint, and see the attributes inspector in the utilities bar (the bar on the right side, the fourth tab in that looks like a slider). There is a checkbox at the bottom that should not be checked. Another possibility is that the view that controller is contained in is not correctly resizing to the screen. -- There are so many things that can go wrong, it's almost impossible to give any more guidance without seeing your code/document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reaching out to Apple on how to deal with this. I upgraded to XCode 6 this afternoon, and I'm experiencing the same thing.  I installed XCode 5.1.1 back onto my machine, cleaned my project and ran it both on the simulator and my device. Everything runs as expected.

In my case, custom Collection View Cells are loaded into a UI Collection View. Inside the nib file, I have set the leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints set such that the object fills its superview. My device is running iOS 7. Those constraints are interpreted as expected in XCode 5.1.1, but there's a change in behavior in XCode 6. The behavior is a complete trainwreck. On top of that, I'm now getting this warning:

**2014-09-22 19:36:04.447 bugIllustration[11817:60b] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2014-09-22 19:36:04.449 bugIllustration[11817:60b] the item width must be less that the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values.**

Comment: The problem i found is that in Xcode 6 constraints for portrait and landscape work perfectly in iOS 8 but in iOS 7 the constraints are somehow overriden by the layout **"iPhone in portrait or landscape"**

Comment: Wow... this is very bizarre. I'm probably going to see the same thing when I upgrade my devices to iOS 8. I took the device of Fabian above. I didn't even know those details existed. lol. Needless to say, no action was required through Interface Builder. I'm trying to avoid having to subclass that Layout Flow class, as I don't think that is necessary. From top to bottom, how are the components in question organized? How did you go about dealing with this?

Comment: I ended up just ignoring the layouts: portrait only, and landscape only. And worked in the layout "iphone portrait or landscape" . I set up constraints in that layout, as you're working with both orientations at the same time it was a bit difficult to set up the constraints on the same screen in the storyboard. The end results of doing it this way aren't as pretty though.

Comment: I think I'm going to take the same direction. I too am ignoring the layout (that simulated metrics -> orientation). This brings back memories when I had the unfortunate luxury of addressing issues regarding orientation when iOS 5 was introduced. lol